# Queue SSH connections to a host

Tags: ssh

I have a script that runs multiple commands on my ARM board. There are many script instances are starting simultaneously, up to 15-20 at once. This causes 1) major lag due to hardware being rather slow 2) SSH connections being dropped due to `MaxSessions` and/or `MaxStartups` limits.

Is it possible to somehow queue the ssh connections ARM, so that they will all use a single connection (like in multiplexing scenario), but one script instance will wait for another to end, before starting to execute its commands?

I **do not want** to edit sshd config on ARM due to several reasons, this is the main limitation and the cause of question.

Comment: Currently I queue not the connections, but script execution itself, via `exec 3<> /tmp/arm-test-${arm_ip}; flock 3`. However it feels that there should be a better way.

Comment: But, scripts generally run all commands in series. If yours are running in parallel, are you sure that's not because your script is deliberately parallelizing them and you should _remove_ that instead of trying to add something more?

Comment: @grawity I agree. But the scripts in question are unit tests runners, started during multithreaded c++ build process. In theory, I probably could make my build system queue them, but from here it seems that it is more of "host X is slow, connections to it should be queued" rather than "unit tests should not run in parallel". I might be wrong, though.